# Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers - Complex custom field

Tags: sitecore, custom-fields, web-forms-for-marketers

The client wants to be able to display, within a WFFM form, a list of Sitecore items (each item containing an image & some HTML text), each item next to a checkbox to allow the end user to pick one or more of these items.

Within the form designer, for this particular field, we would like to have an item selector which can be used by the content editor to pick and choose which items to display in the list.

Is this something feasible in WFFM? Are there examples of complex custom form fields that I could take a look at? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that what I asked can be easily accomplished with the ChechboxList field type already provided by WFFM and some CSS styling to handle the content of each item.
Thanks and sorry for the post.

Comment: Well you may as well acept your own answer then!